# Problemas con memoria en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy tratando de hacer una app en la que se muestren imagenes + otros datos asociados, pero me está pasando que cada vez que intento ejecutar el programa, me da el error de "Vaya! se ha producido un error al mostrar esta página web. Código de error: Out of memory".

Por otro lado mi código en PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$consulta = "SELECT progennom,pp.PreProPre1, progencod,ip.ImaAsoIma FROM productogenerico p 
         INNER JOIN precioproducto pp ON p.progenid=pp.proid
         LEFT JOIN imagenasociada ip ON p.progenid=ip.perid";
$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
$listado = array();
while($fila=$resultado->fetch_array()){
$producto["progennom"]=$fila['progennom'];
$producto["PreProPre1"]=$fila['PreProPre1'];
$producto["progencod"]=$fila['progencod'];
$producto["ImaAsoIma"]=base64_encode($fila['ImaAsoIma']);
array_push($listado, $producto);
}

echo json_encode($listado);
$resultado->close(); 
?>
```

Cabe aclarar que cambié los valores de memory_limit, post_max_size y upload_max_filesize dentro del archivo php.ini

Y por último adjunto captura de pantalla de dicho error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, que valor le asignaste al MEMORY_LIMIT? Considera también el valor de la variable pero desde la configuración de Apache. https://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-change-memory-limit-php-apache-server-t53.html

Comment: Le asigné 8192M a memory_limit, idem con post_max_size y upload_max_filesize

Comment: ¿Puede ser que tenga que hacer algún cambio al código hecho en PHP?

Comment: Esto te pasa cuando le das clic al botón de enviar? En ese caso sería un problema en la solicitud que intentas hacerle al servidor y si tendría que ver con el código, que te aparece en tu ventana de Red, de Developer tools en Chrome? 
De cualquier manera puedes verificar cuál es el estado actual en el que se encuentra la memoria dentro de tu servidor Apache, para verificar tus configuraciones sólo incluye esto: ```<? phpinfo(); ?>``` en cualquier documento php.

Comment: Lo que estoy intentando hacer en realidad es una App en Android en la cual se muestre un listado con imagenes y su descripción correspondiente (con conexión de BD mediante PHP)

Comment: Siento problema serio de optimización y es posible que json_encode no pueda manejar la enorme cantidad de datos de las imágenes de la BD. Por ejemplo, una imagen 1280x720 tiene más de 1/4 de millón de caracteres, y suponiendo que ese query traiga 50 resultados sería un array enorme, y peor para el servidor es que hayan varios usuarios conectados. Nunca se deben guardar imágenes en la BD, almacénalas en un directorio y en la BD solo tienes referencias del nombre del archivo de imagen.

Comment: @aeportugal ¿Entonces no uso json_encode?

Comment: Si, pero con las referencias del nombre de las imágenes, no con los datos en base64. Algo que podrías hacer, solo para probar, es quitar del query `progencod,ip.ImaAsoIma` y comentar la línea `$producto["ImaAsoIma"]=base64_encode($fila['ImaAsoIma']);` Si ya no da el error de memoria, entonces ese es el problema. Si sigue mandando lo mismo, entonces ya habrá que ver otra cosa.

Comment: Acabo de probar con haber quitado del query ip.ImaAsoIma, y haber comentado la linea $producto["ImaAsoIma"]=base64_encode($fila['ImaAsoIma']); y funcionó bien, obviamente las imagenes no las muestra, pero no da el error de la memoria

Comment: Pero mi idea es poder mostrar las imagenes, pero como bien dije, tengo el problema de la memoria

Comment: @aeportugal no me quedó muy claro eso que dices de hacerlo con las referencias del nombre de las imagenes  ¿a que te refieres?

Comment: Necesitas guardar la ubicación de la imagen, nunca guardas la imagen, sólamente la ubicación en donde se encuentra pero creo que ya necesitarías hacer otra pregunta ya que se rompería con las conductas de StackOverflow. Suerte.

Comment: @Eduardo ¿Sería hacer una pregunta sobre como guardar la ubicación de la imagen?

Comment: Así es @StephanieRM

Comment: Gracias ! @Eduardo , lo tendré en cuenta!

Comment: Las imágenes se guardan en un directorio. O sea cada imagen tendrá una ruta/nombreimagen.jpg, por ejemplo. En la BD debe ir ese nombre. La consulta SQL devolverá la ruta junto a otros datos, y con ella puedes mostrar la imagen en el html, o servirla desde tu API. Si un producto tiene más de una imagen, puedes (1) usar una tabla de rutas de imagenes, o (2) ponerle un identificador a los archivos: id001_01.jpg, id001_02.jpg, etc; y que el servidor traiga todas las imágenes _xx.jpg del id solicitado. Hay muchas ventajas de tener las imágenes en archivos y no dentro de la BD.